# Do these motors really have enough torque to lift 130 pounds

Tags: motor, torque

I was looking at these dc motors and I converted the torque to force at a meter distance and I got that two of them should be able to lift over 130 pounds, is this right? http://www.active-robots.com/high-torque-dc-servo-motor-10rpm-with-step-dir-drive There has to be some catch i am not seeing

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get that number?

The first page of the [datasheet posted on the page you linked](https://www.active-robots.com/fileuploader/download/download/?d=0&file=custom%2Fupload%2FFile-1440705232.pdf) states, "Max 15VDC and 7A" (near the top).

So the maximum input power for the motor is $P=IV$, or $P=(7)(15)=105\mbox{W}$.

Mechanical rotating power can be calculated by $P=\tau \omega $, where $\tau$ is torque in Nm and $\omega $ is rotational speed in rad/s.

The motor's top speed is 10 rpm. Multiply by 2$\pi$ to get to rad/m, then divide by 60 to convert to seconds and you get $\omega=10*(6.28/60) = 1.047 \mbox{rad/s} $.

Now, divide input power by rotational speed to get the theoretical maximum torque: $\tau = 105/1.047 = 100\mbox{Nm} $.

Note that this is *Newton* meters; a Newton is about a quarter of a pound, so the maximum force is about 25 pounds.

However, an electric motor is generally only about 80% efficient, so I wouldn't expect more than 20 pounds at 1m, *max*.

Comment: I would also add that the electrical numbers looked kind of more like an absolute rating that an operating/continuous rating, so I would expect actual torque to be even lower. But again, I didn't see an actual torque given anywhere in the datasheet.

Comment: Here is a quote from the product details: "Motor is a Industrial grade 10RPM high torque motor with a massive torque of 120kgcm" that's where I got my number from, yours makes a lot more sense though

Comment: Using the result @Chuck posted, you could add a gear train of about 10:1 (with margin built in for inefficiencies) if you really need to lift 130 lbs using that stepper motor.  Nema 23 gear reducers are readily available from multiple sources.

Comment: @user65909 - multiply your rating, 120kg-cm, by gravitational constant 9.81 to get to Ncm, then divide by 100 to get from cm to meters. This converts the number from 120kg-cm to 11.7Nm. This is far, far lower than my estimate. The theoretical maximum from the input power is 100Nm, so you're burning about 88% of the input power. Maybe the motor torque you state is for the motor before reducing gears?